# How to parameterize an instance of a class with a view bound?

Tags: scala, generics

My motivation is I want an abstract class for sorting functions. Right now that looks like:

```
abstract class Sorter[A <% Ordered[A]]{
  def apply(xs: Seq[A]): Seq[A]
}
```

But I'm not sure how to make a concrete instance of it, i.e.:

```
val mySort = new Sorter {
  def apply(xs: Seq[A]) = { ... }
}
```

I suppose my question is two-fold:

1. Is my abstract class thing even correct?
2. How do I parameterize `mySort`?

Comment: View bounds are deprecated. Do you have to use them?

Comment: No, I don't. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

View bounds are [deprecated](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629) so if you don't have to use them you could write something simple like:

```
  trait Sorter[A] {
    def sort(xs: Seq[A])(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): Seq[A]
  }

  new Sorter[Int] {
    override def sort(xs: Seq[X])(implicit ord: Ordering[X]): Seq[X] = {
      xs.sorted
    }
  }
```

`Sorter` is a trait but could well be an abstract class. Parameterizing instance is done right before the brackets as shown in the example.

On a side note, in Scala I don't see the need for an abstract class (or trait) for ordering things.

The collections already define the `sorted` and `sortBy` methods. So when you have a collection `col` of `A` you can sort it with `col.sorted` provided you have an implicit `Ordering[A]` in scope.

It's up to you to figure out if `Ordering` is what you want or if abstract class and concrete implementation is required.

Keep in mind you can always implement you custom `Ordering` like:

```
new Ordering[Int] {
    override def compare(x: X, y: X) = ???
  }
```

Comment: This is just for practice with scala, thanks though!

Comment: I get an "error: not found: type X" in the new Sorter

Comment: Is `X` in scope? Notice in my example I made `X` a concrete as `Int`

Comment: Is it possible to have a generic?

Comment: Only if `X` is in scope and implements `Comparable` or there is an `Ordering[X]` in scope